# Why a for loop in this argument

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

```
    for (int i=0; i<[rawNumber length]; i++) {
        NSString* chr = [rawNumber substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(i, 1)];
        if(doesStringContain(@"0123456789", chr)) {
            telNumber = [telNumber stringByAppendingFormat:@"%@", chr];
        }
    }
```

What's the logic of this? What does this argument return?

Comment: It doesn't "return" anything.  It appends stuff to telNumber.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it's stripping out all the non-numeric characters, to give you a plain old phone number.

I imagine telNumber is defined before this loop, and uses the value of telNumber somewhere else.

Lets say `rawNumber` held the following value: `(987)-654-3210`.  The for loop runs 14 times total, since that's the length of `rawNumber`.  Each time through, the code gets a single character - the first time it gets the first character, the second time the second character, etc.  Each time through the loop, the code checks if the character is in the string `0123456789`; if it is, then the code appends the character to the telNumber variable.  If the character is not in the list of numbers (if it's `(` or `)` or `-` in our example), then it's just discarded.

Comment: I'm sorry to say I must contest the assertion of 'uses the value of telnumber somewhere else'. I would not find it strange to see code where you take an input, format it in a certain way, and then never use it again. I know it makes zero sense, but I bet 1 of 5 files in my company's codebase has at least one instance of it. That's just how legacy code works, unfortunately. And it makes us maintenance developers very, very sad. :-{ Other than that +1 because that appears to be what it's doing.

Comment: lol @glowcoder, I feel your pain :)  I prefer to work at companies where: 1. the original coder must maintain their own code rather than get to move on to some new project the moment the product was shipped to the client, 2. the original coder's code is periodically reviewed and critiqued (or praised, as the case may be).

Comment: well, for about 14 years, they used contractors to write the bulk of the code. Of the 150 or so who have worked on the 3m+ line codebase in the longer than 3 years ago, about 20 remain, more than half of which are now on different teams. *shrug* at least there's job security!!

Comment: @Thorin - the words *critique* and *criticize* do not inherently carry any negative connotation.

Comment: @Stephen: No, but praise definitely carries a positive connotation, and there have been times in my professional life that I've made sure to point out to a fellow developer just how clear and simple their code was for me to read and that I had no suggestions for improvement.  I'm pretty sure _everyone_ likes hearing that from a co-worker.